# When I deploy a gitblog using, Hugo it looks diffenet from when I see it on localhost. Why?

Tags: github-actions, hugo

I deployed a blog using Hugo via github actions. But the Theme does not look right.
This is what it looks like on localhost, [image]

but in the page deployed by github, it looks like this.
[image]

The layout is different. I pushed all my local files to github, and I can't figure out why it is looking different..

I cleared my browser cache, checked the path, and made sure that I pushed all my local files to Github.

Comment: Seems to be a CSS issue. Are all your CSS files pushed correctly? To the correct locations?

Comment: please delete all references to chatGPT ... there is only one thing worse than posting a chatGPT answer, and that is posting a picture of text instead of posting text

Comment: I recommend the browsers inspector and network tools, to see what happens when you load your page. Are there requests that fails? For CSS files?

Comment: I opened the inspect in the website, and the console shows me this error
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` to my_style.css file, where all my css sources are in. 
But I checked my github, and there are are the files uploaded correctly.

Comment: Check the actual request. Is the path for the request what you expect? Is the CSS file really located at that path? Try loading the CSS file in a tab in your browser (not through the normal page), do you still get the error?

Comment: I'm new to CSS and html so I'm really lost... How do I find the path for the request ? 
When searching for this kind of error I found that you have to add <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/style.css" | relURL}}"> to your html file, but I really don't get where to put this code into..

Comment: I figured out the request url. It is Request URL: https://ddoddii.github.io/css/my_style.css 

but my site's name is https://ddoddii.github.io/Digital_Garden/   
so the request is wrong. 

How do I fix the request url to my actual css file?